# Axiom of choice in Theorem of Tychonoff

Tags: general-topology

Let $I$ be an arbitrary Indexset and let $(X_i,\mathcal{T}_i) \: (i \in I)\:$ be Topological spaces and $X:=\prod\limits_{i \in I} X_i$ the product space equipped with the product topology.

In a version of the proof of Thychonoffs Theorem there will be shown that for each $i \in I$ there exist $x_i \in X_i \setminus A_i$ where $A_i \subset X_i$ are some proper subsets. This will be used to define $x \in X$ with $\pi_i(x)=x_i$.

my Question: Does the existence of $x \in X$ with $\pi_i(x)=x_i$ require the axiom of choice?
(I know that it will be also needed for Zorns Lemma in this proof)

Comment: With the detail provided, it quite looks like it does: you are quite literally saying that given a function $F:I\to \text{Sets}$ such that $F(i)\ne \emptyset$ for all $i$, there is a function $f:I\to \bigcup_{i\in I}F(i)$ such that $f(i)\in F(i)$ for all $i$.

Comment: @Gae.S. Thank you! I already thought about that fact. For my Question I need that $\prod \limits_{i \in I} X_i\setminus A_i$ is not empty (so not  that $X$ is not empty...). Therefore here we cant make a case distinction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is YES, **unless** the situation is specific enough that you can *build* a "choice function", that is, by saying "let $x$ be defined by picking, for every $i$, the one $x_i$ such that...".

In general there is no way to do that, and this is the reason why you need the axiom of choice to prove that $X$ is not *empty* already.

Comment: (though if $X$ is empty, then it is compact) :)

Comment: @Gae.S. :-) $\,$

Answer (score 0):

Yes! In fact, the axiom of choice is equivalent to the following:

> If all $X_i$ are non-empty, then the product $\prod_{i \in I} X_i$ is non-empty.